# How to read a spring property value straight into an xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties

I have an xml file that contains values that define a java object, the values are processed via a java method to handle some specific tasks, the xml file has the below architecture :

```
<javaObject>
    <attr1>value1</attr1>
    <attr2>${property.name}</attr2>
    <attr3>value3</attr3>
</javaObject>
```

My goal is to get the **attr2** from the property file, I've tried  **${property.name}** but it's not working, I've also tried
<property name="property.name" value="${property.name} />

At runtime, I get a NULL when I call the value of **attr2**

What is the best way to implement that ?

Comment: ...it depends! E.g. "at build time" you could do it with a [maven/gradle plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)/ant task or similar!

Comment: .."at runtime", you'd prefer a "templating engine" like thymeleaf, velocity, ... (ideally something, that you already use)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you unmarshal the object and want to work with the value of proeprty.name?
You can inject the value of property.name in your class via

```
@Value("${property.name}")
String propertyName
```